# pacemaker cluster heavy load with sbd and noop scheduler

Tags: linux, cluster, pacemaker

Anybody have experience with nood scheduler? i know the sbd process is a real time process, so with default linux io scheduler cfq, the sbd process works very well on high io heave load.

The noop scheduler only merge the io request in fifo queue, can i have problem with my cluster using nood scheduler with sbd?

Thanks